# Solving a nonlinear optimization problem with KKT by implementing fmin_slsqp()

Tags: optimization, scipy, nonlinear-optimization, inequality

I want to solve a non-linear optimization problem. I was trying to solve it with KKT, but after all, I realized that it is hard to write code to solve this.

I want to know the optimal payment allocation that minimizes the repayment period until I pay off all the debts. Below is the function of my objective equation - My logic was to get the payoff period for each debt and minimize the sum:

```
 My_Loans = {
    'Name' : ['A', 'B','C','D'],
    'Principal' : [350, 2000, 600, 750],
    'APR' : [6, 4, 4, 5]}

My_Loans = pd.DataFrame(My_Loans)
PV = My_Loans['Principal']
APR = My_Loans['APR']

def repayment_period(PV, APR, PMT):
    '''inputs are in lists format. PV is the principal amount, APR is Annual Percentage Rate, and PMT will be my variable which represents the monthly payment.'''

    num_loans = len(PV)
    times = []
   
    for j in range(num_loans):
        i = (APR[j]/12)/100
        accrued_interest = PV[j] * i
        N = round(-(log(1-((PV[j]*i)/PMT[j])))/log(1+i))
        times.append(N)
        total_period = sum(times)
        
    return total_period
```

and it has one inequality constraint which is the sum of PMT (variable) < 2000 (the sum of monthly allocation must be less than 2000).

```
def ieq_constraint(x):
    return np.atleast_1d(np.sum(x)-2000)

from scipy import optimize as pf
op.fmin_slsqp(how_long, np.array([0]), ieqcons=[ieq_constraint])
```

But I can't get this to work. What can I try next? I am open to better approaches if necessary.

Comment: SLSQP can solve NLPs with constraints directly. Why are you trying to use a KKT formulation? Also, SLSQP assumes smooth functions, so never, never, never use something like `round()` in your functions. Nonlinear problems with discrete structures are called MINLPs and they require different types of solvers.

Comment: I have seen SLSQP used for portfolio management, but I haven't actually worked on it. I will try to study SLSQP first. Thank you :)

Comment: I have never seen that. I only have seen commercial solvers when talking to financial institutions.